# helpExtract function does not work in R 3.1.1 and knitr 1.6.10

Tags: r, latex, knitr, sweave

I took the following code from [here](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/7586769) written by @AnandaMahto. This function was working fine previously but stop working with `R 3.1.1` and `knitr 1.6.10`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<echo=FALSE>>=
library(devtools)
source_gist("https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/7586769")
@

\Sexpr{knit_child(textConnection(helpExtract(cor, section="Arg", type = "s_text")),
options = list(tidy = FALSE, eval = FALSE))}

\Sexpr{knit_child(textConnection(helpExtract(cor, type = "s_code")), 
options = list(tidy = FALSE, eval = FALSE))}

<<tidy=TRUE>>=
## normal R code
args(lm)
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: Let's see if @AnandaMahto has any solution.

Comment: Strange. If the contents of the function are run line-by-line, they seem to output what is expected....

Comment: @AnandaMahto: Does it work for you?

Comment: Like I mentioned--If I manually walk through the steps in the function (not using the function), everything seems to work. Once you put it in a function, it fails on the first line--can't find the help file.

Comment: Don't know if `getHelpFile` has changed or `Rd2txt`.

Comment: I think `source_gist` makes problem. This works if I define the function within the .Rnw.

Comment: @kohske, why would that be the case?

Comment: Even `source()` doesn't work.

Comment: @MYaseen208, it seems to work if you use it from a package. Presently, [it's part of my "SOfun" package.](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun). So, it should work if you replace `library(devtools);source_gist("https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/7586769")` with `library(SOfun)` (after installing the package, of course!)

Comment: I found finally that `library(devtools)` causes this problem. So it works by replacing the first chunk with `devtools::source_gist("https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/7586769")`

Comment: Not inspected yet, but I imagine that this is because `devtools` masks `?` and `help`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an ad-hoc solution, you can do it by avoiding `library(devtools)`

```
<<echo=FALSE>>=
devtools::source_gist("https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/7586769")
@
```

But the essential solution is to modify the `helpExtract` function.
At line #3, `utils:::.getHelpFile(help(A))` should be `utils:::.getHelpFile(utils::help(A))`

This is caused by some `deparse` and `substitute` chains. 
I'm not sure if this is a bug of `devtools` but at least I think this is a bad behavior of `devtools` package, so I'll let @hadley know about this behavior.

Comment: +1 for the sleuthing. As I mentioned in the comments, it seems like loading the function from a package also works.

Comment: Yes, that's because the search path is different inside a package, so even if user call `library(devtools)` the call of `help` inside the package refers `utils::help`.

Comment: Cool. I'll modify the function to explicitly refer to `utils::help` then.